# Not able to access wso2 ESB management console with default credentials

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Hi I downloaded and ran the WSO2 ESB without modifying anything.
when I attempt to login with the default admin creds, it fails

checking the console i see the following

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-07-20 19:08:53,212]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-07-20 19:08:53,206+0000] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

Has this ever happened to anyone? assistance needed to resolve this issue

```
WSO2 ESB version: 4.9.0
java 8
```

Other info:

```
OS: linux
platform: vagrant machine (ubuntu/trusty64)
```

Browsers used:
Chrome, safari

Client OS: Mac

Ports exposed:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9443, host: 9443
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9763, host: 9763
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8282
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9443, host: 9443
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9763, host: 9763
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8280, host: 8280
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8243, host: 8243
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9445, host: 9445
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9765, host: 9765
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8282, host: 8282
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8245, host: 8245
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9444, host: 9444
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9764, host: 9764
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7614, host: 7614
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9446, host: 9446
```

Thanks

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oTwf.png
[image: imageone]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRUzC.png
[image: img2]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more information? The INFO suggests it did log in. Were there any error messages? What exactly happened? How did you log in?

Comment: i edited with screenshots, there were no errors

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you used Username: admin and Password: admin.

According to the log, it looks like you logged into ESB. Check your firewalls or browser. It may have disturbance which will blocking the access.

If you still get the issue, please identify the browser you use.

Comment: There was no error actually and i was using chrome and safari to test

Comment: so I ran the ESB on the mac directly and it works now..seems something was blocking it while running in vagrant as you said